# How to copy 2-d lists?

Tags: python, list

```
a = [[0],[0]]
b = list(a)
b[0][0] = 3
print(a)
```

Returns `[[3],[0]]` and I want it to be `[[0],[0]]`. In other words, how do I copy a list which contains lists and create a new list which can be altered independent of the original list?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please visit this link [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before proceeding any further.

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to make your question better! Also include the programming language as a tag, this will make question more specific and it will get more views :).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a deep copy:

```
import copy
a = [[0],[0]]
b = copy.deepcopy(a)
b[0][0] = 3
print(a)
```

Output:

```
[[0], [0]]
```